# Error with airflow while running airflow webserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, airflow

I am trying to install apache airflow using wsl on windows 10.
I am following this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/run-apache-airflow-on-windows-10-without-docker-3c5754bb98b4

I was able to run: airflow db init and airflow scheduler, without any errors.

Upon running airflow webserver, I encountered following error:

```
File "/home/glinty/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: job
[SQL: SELECT job.id AS job_id, job.dag_id AS job_dag_id, job.state AS job_state, job.job_type AS job_job_type, job.start_date AS job_start_date, job.end_date AS job_end_date, job.latest_heartbeat AS job_latest_heartbeat, job.executor_class AS job_executor_class, job.hostname AS job_hostname, job.unixname AS job_unixname
FROM job
WHERE job.id = ? AND job.job_type IN (?)]
[parameters: (2, 'SchedulerJob')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

How to overcome this error.

Comment: Try this out. It takes care of everything. Tested on WSL for Windows 10. https://github.com/caxefaizan/airflow_kubernetes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem(not sure what resolved this), in my case:

1) I changed the wsl version from 1 to 2. (Restarted pc after this)

2) enabled virtualization windows feature(Restarted pc after this)

3) created an account using this command:

        airflow users create --username admin --password admin --firstname  --lastname  --role Admin --email abc@gmail.com

 4) delete ALL files in AIRFLOW_HOME directory and run airlow db init.

 Then, ran airflow webserver command.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is `no such table: job` so the database migrations must not have been run. The article referenced uses an older version of Airflow with a command (`airflow initdb`) that no longer works. Use `airflow db init` instead.

Comment: I used airflow db init command since airflow version was 2.2.4 .

Comment: Can you check if the table exists in the database?